# A bit stuck on a quite simple proof that involves the floor value of two parameters

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

Today, I have to write a proof to the following arguement:

**For every $x,y \in \mathbb{R} \hspace{0.1cm}$ , $x\le y \implies \lfloor x\rfloor \le \lfloor \:y\rfloor \:$**

So, I tried to write something

---

**The proof:**

Let $x,y\in \mathbb{R}, \hspace{0.1cm} x\le y$.

According to the properties of the floored value (I can reference them like this) :

1. $\hspace{0.1cm} x-1 < \lfloor x \rfloor \leq x$
2. $\hspace{0.1cm} y-1 < \lfloor y \rfloor \leq y$

$x\le y \iff x-1\le y-1$

---

So, I don't have much clue what to do next from here. I see that the right side of inequality no.2 $\ge $ the right side of inequality no.1. $(x\le y)$

And that the left side of inequality no.2 $\ge $ the left side of inequality no.1 $(x-1\le y-1)$

So I think I can "infer" that the middle term of ineqality no.2 $\ge$ the middle term of inequlity no.1 ($x\le y \rightarrow \lfloor x\rfloor \le \lfloor \:y\rfloor\:$).

But of course, I can't "infer" in a proof, and I don't think I could say such a thing (if it's even correct).

Is there something I miss?

---

Thank you for reading.

Comment: The properties you listed aren’t strong enough alone. I think you need use the definition of the floor function directly. It may help to write $x=\lfloor x\rfloor+\{x\}$, and similarly for $y$, where $0\le\{x\}<1$ is the fractional part of $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lfloor x \rfloor \le x \le y$

$\lfloor x \rfloor$ is an integer that is less than or equal to $y$

The greatest integer that is less than or equal to $y$ must be greater than or equal to $\lfloor x \rfloor$

$\implies \lfloor y \rfloor$ must be greater than or equal to $\lfloor x \rfloor$

$\implies \lfloor x \rfloor \le \lfloor y \rfloor$